# how to add google api key and callback function using a function in google places api

Tags: angularjs, google-places-api

I want to send my google api key and callback from the angularjs file, not in the URL of the google places api. but I don't know the way to do this.
Please tell me the way of doing this using angularjs from another file, not on the same HTML file. Basically, I want to add all the functions that are needed by google places api like initAutocomplete, fillinaddress and geolocate from another file using angularjs also my api key.

For now, I am doing this as

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key==APIKEY&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
async defer></script>
```

But I don't want api key and initAutocomplete here

Comment: Please be more specific and attach sample codes, examples demonstrating what you want to do.

Comment: @NirajPaudel okay, I am editing my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my solution after lots of searches

> Here is my solution to add api key or script using function

```
 $scope.loadScript = function() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js? 
 sensor=false&callback=initialize';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $scope.initialize();
    }, 500);
 }
```

> And for google places library functions I have created an angularjs directive.